# Docker giving nameserver error upon docker pull

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu-22.04

I recently setup a new linux machine, running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I installed Docker on it, and Portainer to make viewing easier.

I am attempting to install a mysql image, however when running the command docker pull, either in portainer, or via CLI, I am met with the following error:

`Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution`

In my /etc/netplan config file, the nameservers are set correctly to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, and if I try to set them in resolv.conf, they just default back to the original one upon save.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens if you type `host registry-1.docker.io` on the command line?

Comment: @JaromandaX I get this ";; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused"

Comment: does the system have internet access in general? does `resolve.conf` contain a warning that any changes will be lost or that the contents is `Generated by something or other`

Comment: Ive just noticed my resolv.conf file has become blank, and /run/resolvconf folder is missing? Not sure when this happened... @JaromandaX